# rsyslog forward with ;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format

Tags: rsyslog

I am trying to forward rsyslog with `;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format`
It works fine for an all log forward: `*.* @@syslogserver.com:6789;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format`

But does anyone know how it can be implemented on specific rules?

```
if ($msg contains_i and so on)<br>
 action(type="omfwd" target="syslogserver.com" port="6789" protocol="tcp"
            action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *rules*, I'm assuming you mean *conditionals* or *[filters](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html)*.

A simple if statement can be done like this:

```
if $msg contains 'test' then
    action(type="omfwd" template="RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format" ...)
```

... which can also be chained:

```
if $programname == 'my_program' and $msg contains 'test' then
    action(type="omfwd" template="RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format" ...)
```

... or be done with a collection of statements:

```
if $programname == 'my_program' then {
    action(type="omfwd" ...)
    if $msg contains 'test' then
        action(type="omfwd" template="RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format" ...)
    else
        action(type="omfwd" ...)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I meant conditionals :) But is it possible to add ;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format to a conditional?

Comment: Do you mean filtering for a specific template or using a template in an action?

Comment: Apoloigies, I did not see you had written "action(type="omfwd" template="RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format" ...)" - I will try that asap :)